# Witcher 3 Wild Hunt: Graphics broken

Tags: the-witcher-3, graphics-card

I've downloaded Witcher 3 Wild Hunt on a Windows 10 PC with GTX 750 Ti. I find a lot of the times I fire up the game, the graphics are broken (ref. image below).

[image: broken graphics]

Other times I'm able to play the game with my CPU utilization near 100% and RAM at 90% (4 GB DDR3). The machine doesn't perform slowly when the game is on (in fact desktop environement is much faster than when some Ubisoft games are running), so I wonder what might be the cause. Any thoughts?

Comment: What are your settings? Resolution, texture detail, etc... Do you have the latest GPU drivers installed. The Witcher 3 is an incredibly demanding game so I would not be surprised if 4GB is not enough memory. CD Projekt Red has done an absolutely astounding job in optimizing the game but you should really meet the minimum 6GB requirement; get 8GB, RAM is cheap. It's quite possible your RAM is swapping to your disk and that is causing a delay/failure in loading graphics. Try lowering the settings or get more RAM.

Comment: FWIW, my system used to have 8GB RAM paired with a 2GB HD7870 and made GTA 5 crash. The error stated that I ran out of RAM so even meeting the recommended specs in RAM can prove to be problematic. I upgraded to 16GB and it never happened again.

Comment: Resolution is perpetually low for me (at low, witcher starts correctly 40% of the times I've tried). I have the latest drivers (Nvidia display driver 375.57 from this weekend). But unlike for other games Nvidia Geforce Experience said it cannot optimize this game (I thought it may have some thing to do with CD Project Red being an almost indie studio). I had to turn it down from ultra manually. I keep thinking since CPU is at 100% and RAM at 90% (RAM is not fully utilized) so it must be CPU or graphics card.

Comment: **(1)** Nvidia GeForce Experience does not acknowledge 85% of the games I own (total of 90-ish which range from 1-10 years old) and the only thing it provides is a central area to tweak the already available in-game settings. **(2)** Those so-called "AAA publishers" can easily learn a thing or a million from CD Projekt Red. Anyways, RAM at 90% usually means it is swapping to disk. [Check out if your system is swapping RAM to disk.](http://superuser.com/questions/917517/how-do-i-know-how-much-swap-is-used-on-windows-7).

Comment: will check out the swap in a while. I agree Projekt Red has done an amazing job here. in ur experience whats RAM% like in healthily performing games ?

Comment: paging is low 3.271% when game on and 2.845% when I close it. it may be the graphics card too. Min req says GTX 660/HD7870 which is much higher than my 750 Ti

Comment: The GTX 660 is only 11% better than the 750 TI according to http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/high_end_gpus.html and that is not too bad but I would recommend downloading GPU-Z and monitoring the stress level of your GPU and seeing if any throttling is occurring. As for the normal RAM usage, it varies heavily based on the settings you are using and how old/new the game is. I have 16GB at home and I play on Ultra settings with my GTX 970 so I will hopefully play the game tonight and can let you know tomorrow. You do not have any mods installed, correct?

Comment: Does this issue only occur once you've loaded a save file? Does this happen on the main menu? What version of The Witcher 3 are you running? Mine is running 1.31 currently with both DLCs (Blood & Wine and Hearts of Stone). [Can you take a screenshot of your graphics settings and post it here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9umP.png) I might be able to suggest more optimal settings for your hardware.

Comment: Does this happen during certain weather conditions? Such as rain, or cloudy, or at night/day? Or is it completely random?

Comment: well at 1st it used to happen when save game loaded at a place close to water (and outside at night, maybe) but right now, it's just happening anywhere. mine is 1.31 without the DLCs. my graphics setting is set to the game's "Preset-Low" I didn't tweak any of those preset settings.

Comment: just FYI i posted that swap% using perfmon as posted in the link you gave but i also have [rainmeter](http://orig09.deviantart.net/8795/f/2013/188/f/5/rainmeter___information_overload_1_0_by_gluzer-d6cgy0x.png) which shows high (60%+) SWAP usage when witcher 3 runs

Comment: I would trust the 60% swap that rainmeter is providing because the minimum requirements state 6GB so 2GB being swapped to disk is about 50-60%

Comment: I've honestly never analyzed the page swap so I am not sure if the instructions provided for perfmon were accurate and I am not familiar with how to read the numbers.

Comment: I guess this comment doesn't help you. However, I recommend to upgrade your hardware. Witcher 3 Wild Hunt is a fantastic game! Playing only on low is a shame (don't get me wrong :D ). I would go for at least 8 gigabytes of RAM and a better graphics card, for example a GTX 960. Depending of your current CPU-model it's useful to also upgrade that component. As soon as you played on higher graphics you won't regret anything, I promise :)

Comment: Ah dude.. SPOILER ALERT, came here looking for an answer for a friend and was like wait what Ciri becomes a witcher.... I am going to put mabu and MonkeyZues comments into an answer so that this can be accepted as answered.

Comment: Where did you "download"? Game version?

Comment: Sry abt the spoiler Daniel. Witcher 3 is a game of many possible endings btw

Answer (score 1):

Hard to pinpoint the issue but here are some steps that might solve this glitch:

1. Verify integrity (should go without saying).
2. Delete /bin/ folder in your W3 directory, then verify. It'll redownload a lot of stuff. That used to fix a lot of patch-induced bugs.
3. Reinstall
4. Check GPU drivers, rollback them to earlier stable version.
5. Physically remove your GPU, dust off the socket and connectors.

For certain that's not a RAM issue. It's not the power of your card either. People have ran this game on ancient rigs with graphics modded to look like PS1 without such glitches.

It's either a) game files issue, since ground textures are missing (not super popular, but a known occasional bug) b) driver issue c) graphics card issue. Cards get old. Artifacts are a sign of old age.

I recommend the order I suggested, as it is from least intrusive to most intrusive. Also, it's logical to fix gamefiles to brand new before starting to mess with GPU drivers/GPU itself.

Answer (score -1):

Seems that is RAM problem. 4GB is not enough for TW3. GPU is good enough for playing at Low settings.

Anyway, update your drivers to the lastest version.

Answer (score -2):

The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt is a game that is quite demanding on graphics and RAM. As mabu says; upgrading your hardware will fix the problem.

Typical Hardware Upgrades:

- RAM to minimum of 6 Gig (Preferably 8 Gig)
- Graphics Card: GTX 960 - as suggested by mabu

Or as MonkeyZues has suggested you can download software in order to accurately monitor how much stress your hardware components are going through - this will help with maybe only upgrading those specific hardware units instead of upgrading your whole system, could save money.

Comment: Low system specs shouldn't cause graphical issues, only low performance.

Comment: That's my point. I've played many games. seen this kind of broken graphics once before- Far cry 1 on a Pentium IV machine with an XFX card

Comment: In my experience with Witcher 3: The Wild Hunt, specifically, a low RAM causes graphical glitches as the picture shows. @ari7628 Did upgrading to 8Gig RAM not solve this? As your comment in response to mabu implies it did?